# how to get soapObjet return in AsyncTask with kSoap2 in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, asmx

i want to call ASMX web service , 
**how to get back SoapObject or List in activity from doInBackground**
, web service work fine , it display values on log file 
, my code is , file whire i call web service

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import android.util.Log;

public class WebserviceMainCategory {


    static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/loadProductCatagory";
    static String METHOD_NAME = "loadProductCatagory";
    static String NAME_SPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    static String URL = "http://74.53.87.146/seharwebservice/Service.asmx";
    public  List<String> main_items = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static String[] namess ;
    static int s ;
    public static SoapObject soap;

    public  SoapObject webServiceMain_list() {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAME_SPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSe = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        httpTransportSe.debug = true;


        try {

            httpTransportSe.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object result = envelope.getResponse();

            soap = (SoapObject) result;

            /*
            SoapObject result2nd = (SoapObject) result;
            s = result2nd.getPropertyCount();
                        //String[]arrayLis = new String[s];

                        namess = new String[s];
                        for(int i=0; i<result2nd.getPropertyCount(); i++)
                        {
                            Log.d("ddd", result2nd.getPropertyAsString(i));
                            namess[i]=result2nd.getPropertyAsString(i);
                            Log.d("array", namess[i]);
                            main_items.add(result2nd.getPropertyAsString(i));
                        }
                    */


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return soap;    
    }

}
```

where i create AsyncTask  class

```
class Main_itemsList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,  SoapObject> {

    @Override
    protected SoapObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
        WebserviceMainCategory mAuth = new WebserviceMainCategory();

        return  mAuth.webServiceMain_list();

    }

    public void execute(SoapObject aa) {


    }
    }
```

how to get response in main activity ,

like code in my activity

SoapObject soap = new Main_itemsList().execute();

our

ListArray aa = new Main_itemsList().execute();

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like

```
private SoapObject aa;
class Main_itemsList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SoapObject> {
    @Override
    protected SoapObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // this is executed in a background thread.
        // the result is returned to the UI thread via onPostExecute
        WebserviceMainCategory mAuth = new WebserviceMainCategory();
        return  mAuth.webServiceMain_list();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject result) {
        // aa is inside your Activity / Fragment which
        // contains this class
        aa = result;
    }
}

// you just need to start the task somewhere
public void onSomething() {
    // this will set "aa" when it's done.
    new Main_itemsList().execute();
}
```

if you start an `AsyncTask` it will do whatever you defined in `doInBackground` in a background thread. The result you return there is transported back to the UI thread to `onPostExecute`. In there you take the result and "publish" it to your activity or fragment.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. i make aa Static SoapObject .. when i call function it did no give me error BUT when i access the aa SoapObject it give me error , even it do not prints the value of aa on log file 

 new Main_itemsList().execute();
   
    for(int i=0; i<aa.getPropertyCount(); i++)
    {
     Log.d("soap Valut ", aa.getPropertyAsString(i));
    }

Comment: You can't access `aa` immediately since it is not set until the `AsyncTask` finishes at some point in the future. If you want to print it, trigger that from `onPostExecute`

Comment: one question .. i want to call web service for Login , get username and password for asmx web service , how to force delay for some time to get username and password form webservice ... i call sleep but application crash .. thanks

Comment: If you do things async you don't wait for them to happen, instead you use the event that happens when the async thing finishes to trigger all the updates. In your case: start login task, do nothing then and just leave the UI in some "pls wait I am loading stuff" state and once the loading finishes you update the UI again to proceed